# Proper way to install pip on Ubuntu

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to install the latest version of pip (currently 8.1.2) on the official ubuntu/trusty64 Vagrant box. The box comes with Python 2.7.6 and 3.4.3 pre-installed with apt-get.

I read the [pip installation doc](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/) and it contains the following warning:

> Be cautious if you're using a Python install that's managed by your
>   operating system or another package manager. get-pip.py does not
>   coordinate with those tools, and may leave your system in an
>   inconsistent state.

Does that mean I cannot install pip using get-pip.py and I am limited to install an older version of it from apt-get?

If there is a better way of installing it, what would it be?

Thanks

Comment: Use get-pip and stick to using pip when installing packages, I have always used get-pip on all my ubuntu unstalls without any issues, you could also just use a virtualenv or pyenv

Comment: If you don't want Python 3 installed, I would remove it.  Having two versions can become a nuisance.

Comment: @JordanBonitatis: Python 3 is required for a lot of things in Ubuntu to work.  Having it around is only a nuisance if you're in the habit of accidentally adding '3' to the ends of command names.

Comment: @jwodder - Ah - you're totally right.  I am using 12.04, but yes, Ubuntu has been relying on Python 3 since 14.04

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I believe that you can install it on Ubuntu with

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

for Python 3. Sure, it's an older version but its functionality is there.

Comment: The apt-get version is a few releases  behind what you get using get-pip

Comment: might need `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install python-pip`

Comment: You might need to enable the `universe` repository for the package to be found in the repositories. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63591163/python3-pip-has-no-installation-candidate

Answer (score 7):

Try download install package from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip#downloads and use `python setup.py install`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that'll essentially be the same thing as just running `get-pip.py`.

Answer (score 1):

if it is outdated you can use the following command:
 `sudo pip install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu OS with Python2.7 You can follow below steps

> apt-get update
>
> apt-get upgrade
>
> apt-get install python-pip

To check install pip version

> pip --version

OR

If you are using Ubuntu OS with Python3 You can follow below steps

> apt-get update
>
> apt-get upgrade
>
> apt-get install python3-pip

To check install pip3 version

> pip3 --version

Answer (score 0):

The proper commands to install pip and pip3 should be the following:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip python3-pip --yes
sudo python3 -m pip install pip --upgrade --force-reinstall
sudo python -m pip install pip --upgrade --force-reinstall # this must come after upgrading pip3
```

The last two lines get **pip3** and **pip** up-to-date.  The last line is critical because it re-associates **pip** with python 2.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on ubuntu 18.0.4:

```
1- sudo apt-get update
2- sudo apt-get upgrade
3- sudo apt-get install python-pip
4- pip -V
```

Answer (score 0):

```
              Install in the ubuntu software,Python,django and pip
```

sudo apt update 
sudo apt install python2
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py --output get-pip.py
sudo python2 get-pip.py
sudo apt-get install python3-distutils

Answer (score -1):

- `sudo apt-get update;`
- `sudo apt-get install python-pip;`

Once the installation is complete, verify the installation by checking the pip version:

- `pip --version;`