# python3-pip has no installation candidate

Tags: python-3.x, pip

I am having an error after typing:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
```

This is the error:

```
Package python3-pip is not available but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3-pip' has no installation candidate
```

What should I do?

Comment: What are the contents of your file at `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and does the problem go away if you `sudo apt-get update`?

Answer (score 73):

You need to update source list first,
Try running

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade  #Optional
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get upgrade` is unnecessary here.

Comment: why is it unnecessary tho, if I may ask? I though apt-get update only modifies the names in the sense that it only identifies what are the latest packages, I believe to install them we need to run apt-get upgrade

Comment: @yash `sudo apt-get upgrade` will upgrade existing packages. It won't install pip as the question here asks.

Answer (score 18):

hi I had same issue but I ran the following commands to fix it

- sudo add-apt-repository universe
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt install python3-pip

and it solved the problem

Answer (score 11):

The solution is to add the universe repository:

```sh
sudo add-apt-repository universe
```

Then update apt:

```sh
sudo apt update
```

And try again:

```sh
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Comment: this was the best solution for me as i'm running ub20 from a USB drive - running `sudo apt-get update` filled up the cow drive and I had to reset

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue
simply running
sudo apt-get update
solve it

Answer (score 0):

in Debian 11, part of this answer helped me (I invite you to upvote it unix.stackexchange.com, please): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/522758/how-to-install-software-properties-common-in-debian-9/522770#522770

Summarizing, add to `/etc/apt/sources.list` the next line (replacing  by the right Debian version name, as stretch or bullseye):

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ <version-name> main
```

In my case,

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ bullseye main
```

After this, I cold install my missing packages, as `software-properties-common python3-pip vim tree`

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Add these lines.

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic main universe

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main universe

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates main universe

---

Press Ctrl+O to save the file. 
Press Ctrl+X to quit nano.

Then run:

```
sudo apt update sudo apt install python3-pip
```

---

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1254309/not-installing-pip-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**You have to enable the universe's distribution component for all sources.**

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update -y
sudo apt install python3-pip
```