# Unable to locate package python-pytest

Tags: python, installation, package, dependencies, pytest

I had to reset my machine recently, and so have to re-install everything again.

I want to run a `Python` file using `PyTest`.

Bash Terminal:

```sh
me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/dabell/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/composite_key/compositekey/tests$ pytest -s test_composite_key.py

Command 'pytest' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install python-pytest

me@PF2DCSXD:/mnt/c/Users/dabell/Documents/GitHub/workers-python/workers/composite_key/compositekey/tests$ sudo apt install python-pytest
[sudo] password for danielbellhv: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package python-pytest
```

---

I was able to install `pip`, following this post's [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63591233/16105404).

Please let me know if there is anything else I can add to post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to first install pip, as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63591233/16105404):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade  #Optional
sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Then

```
$ pip install pytest
Collecting pytest
  Downloading pytest-6.2.5-py3-none-any.whl (280 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 280 kB 621 kB/s 
Collecting packaging
  Downloading packaging-21.2-py3-none-any.whl (40 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 40 kB 1.1 MB/s 
Collecting iniconfig
  Downloading iniconfig-1.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (5.0 kB)
Collecting pluggy<2.0,>=0.12
  Downloading pluggy-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Collecting py>=1.8.2
  Downloading py-1.10.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (97 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 97 kB 1.1 MB/s
Collecting toml
  Downloading toml-0.10.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=19.2.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from pytest) (19.3.0)
Collecting pyparsing<3,>=2.0.2
  Downloading pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 67 kB 1.1 MB/s
Installing collected packages: pyparsing, packaging, iniconfig, pluggy, py, toml, pytest
  WARNING: The scripts py.test and pytest are installed in '/home/danielbellhv/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.
Successfully installed iniconfig-1.1.1 packaging-21.2 pluggy-1.0.0 py-1.10.0 pyparsing-2.4.7 pytest-6.2.5 toml-0.10.2
```

---

Note:

```
$ pip install python-pytest
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-pytest (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-pytest
```

Answer (score 1):

Installing pip worked for me!

Also to install pytest coverage use the command below:

```
pip install pytest-cov
```