# pip3 not getting installed on Ubuntu

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, installation, pip

I am trying to install pip3 on Ubuntu using the following command
`sudo apt install python3-pip`

And in response, I am getting the following output

[image: The Error]

Package `python3-pip` is not available but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3-pip' has no installation candidate

I just want to install `pip3`, please provide a way to solve this!

Comment: This issue is answered in another [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63591163/python3-pip-has-no-installation-candidate) .. have you tried that?

Answer (score 0):

If python3-pip package is not available in your package manager, it might be due to your package list being outdated or because python3-pip is not available for your specific Ubuntu version or repository.

You can try installing pip for Python 3 using the get-pip.py script provided by the Python Packaging Authority. Here's how:

First, ensure you have python3 and python3-setuptools installed:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3 python3-setuptools
```

Then, download the get-pip.py script:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

Next, run the script with Python 3:

```
sudo python3 get-pip.py
```

After the installation is complete, you can verify that pip3 is installed by checking its version

```
pip3 --version
```